# Issue with using a delimiter on a multiple line text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Let's say that we have a this text file with animals and their color:

```
dog=brown
cat=yellow
bird=red
```

I need to get the color of the animal, so i wrote this method. I call the method with the animal i want the color of in the parameter.

```
public String getAnimal(String animal) throws IOException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(TEXT_FILE).useDelimiter("=");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(sc.nextLine().startsWith(animal)){
                sc.next();
                return sc.next();
            }
            sc.nextLine();
        }
         return null;
    }
```

It only semi works. For example calling `System.out.println(getAnimal("cat"));`, prints:

```
yellow
cat
```

It's like if the scanner ignored the fact that there are any lines and prints anything between the delimiters.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Or there is no question at all.

Comment: If this is the input format you are expecting, you case use `Properties` class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

If this is the input format you are expecting, you case use Properties class (docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

OR

You can use [Apache FileUtils.readLines](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29) to read all the lines. Then split the strings using [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and `=` character to separate the key - value pairs.

Comment: I just want to get whats on a specific line. Is there any way to do this without using any external API?

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716623/960778 to read a text file line by line, then for every line look for the input key (dog/cat/bird)